# Are there any libraries for generating flash swf files or converting svg to swf

Tags: flash, svg

I was wondering if anyone knows of any libraries for programatically creating flash swf files.

Or for creating swf from svg.

Comment: I ended up using SpriteGraphics2D to do what i needed, you can read about it here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267001/save-java2d-to-swf-flash/269714#269714

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect job for [swfmill](http://swfmill.org/) I think you'll find it will allow you to do both, convert SVG to SWF and to create SWF files from code.

Answer (score 3):

[Ming](http://www.libming.org/), which is written in C can generate SWF content.  There are bindings for Ming in Perl via the [SWF module](http://search.cpan.org/~liscovius/SWF-0.4.0-beta6_02/) and I believe it can be used with PHP as well.  As far as SVG to SWF conversion, it looks like there's a [Python program](http://www.flashmagazine.com/news/detail/svg_to_swf_using_ming/) that can do that, but it sounds as though it's still a bit rough around the edges.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [SwfDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swfdotnet/) . It's done in .NET.

Here's an example check this out:

[How to transform JPEG to SWF on the fly](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/jpeg2swf.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It seems swfmill is not as good as the standard mxmlc to convert and embed SVG files.
I tested it on some simple files and it lost all color and font information.

For me, the question is still relevant, because mxmlc also loses some attributes of my SVG files, mainly gradients...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aspose.Flash](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.flash-for-.net/default.aspx) to create SWF files from scratch or from an SVG file. You can get complete help from the Programmer's Guide and Demos. You can also ask question in our forums for any technical issues or concerns.

I'm a member of the Aspose.Flash team.

Answer (score 0):

It's an early days project, so there may be some fiddling, but [Swiffotron](https://github.com/izb/Swiffotron) can load, modify, generate and combine SWF files.