# Open Source Libraries for Rendering Vector Graphics Formats Through Java2D?

Tags: flash, svg, java-2d, eps, vml

What are my options for rendering graphics encoded by Java2D to vector graphics formats such as EPS, SWF, SVG, VML, PDF and others I might not have heard of yet with open source libraries?

[Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) is the most widely-used library for rendering SVG. What other options are there?

[iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) is widely used for rendering PDF. Is there something less functional but possibly simpler?

For [rendering SWF (Flash) from Java2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267001/save-java2d-to-swf-flash), I've found [Transform SWF](http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/transform/) from Flagstone Software very effective, if not intuitive.

Which less-popular libraries, or projects starting out, would be worth looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batik and iText are both good libraries. I've also tried [Apache PDFBox](http://incubator.apache.org/pdfbox/), but I don't think it has support for Java2D.

Regarding iText, although it has extensive capabilities, you can still use it for simple Java2D rendering tasks by way of the [PdfGraphics2D](http://www.1t3xt.info/api/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfGraphics2D.html) class. For a short example of how straightforward this is, see this [link](http://itextdocs.lowagie.com/tutorial/directcontent/graphics2D/index.php).

Here are some other resources that you might want to explore:

- [EpsGraphics2D](http://www.jibble.org/epsgraphics/) (EPS)
- [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) (PDF, PS, SVG with Batik)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is save your Java2D to PostScript, that's really easy without any add-on libraries: See http://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2009/10/08/how-draw-simple-diagrams-easy-way-java2d. You can then use ps2eps to turn the output into EPS, or ps2pdf to turn it into PDF.